# Using the same object in different session

Tags: r, parallel-processing

Is there a way to share a const object between multiple *sessions* in R?

In my current situation I'm willing to run the PAM algorithm and for that it is needed a dissimilarity matrix. The process of creating the matrix in discussion --- of my project --- requires all my random acess memory. But, after generated it takes only 2Gb of Ram. My computer has *raw* 8Gb Ram.

Because of the high dimensionality, the algorithm is slow in reaching its convergence and for that reason, I would like to run in parallel multiple functions. However, my computer doesn't handle another matrix generation but, as the object already exists in another *session* I'm thinking if there is a way to use it.

I hope it is clear. If itsn't, please leave a comment that I will revise my text. Thank you in advance.

*Observations:*

- I have both Windows and Ubuntu OS
- I'm not sure if *session* is the right word

Comment: Eventually related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35352807/sharing-in-memory-data-in-rstudio-server

Comment: AFAIK it's not possible as each R session has its own memory space, and you can't access it outside.

Comment: I may have missed the point, but if you need to run multiple functions in parallel why don't you run them in parallel within a single session instead of running them in multiple sessions?

Comment: Parallel "workers" (R processes) can _only_ share objects with the master R process when those workers are _forked processes_.  Forked processes, which for instance `mclapply()` uses, are only available on Unix and macOS.  On Windows, you can only use workers that run in their own processes (their own "R sessions").  So, you need to use `parallel::mclapply()`, `future::plan(multicore)` or similar.  (FYI, there are other issues with forked processes that may consume your memory, e.g. garbage collection, but should still be better than separate R sessions).

Answer (score 1):

On Ubuntu you can use something like this:

```
# generate 500 objects, divided into 4 clusters.
x <- rbind(cbind(rnorm(100,0,0.5), rnorm(100,0,0.5)),
           cbind(rnorm(150,5,0.5), rnorm(150,5,0.5)),
           cbind(rnorm(100,0,0.5), rnorm(100,5,0.5)),
           cbind(rnorm(150,5,0.5), rnorm(150,0,0.5)))
# generate dstance matrix
y <- dist(x)
# run four clusterings in parallel using forked processes
parallel::mclapply(1:4, function(k) cluster::pam(y, k)$medoids)
```